# how to select tags that are inside certain other tags

Tags: javascript

I want to select all the <"a"> tags on a page that are inside all the <"code"> tags on the page so I can count them, and I want to do this using JavaScript.. how can I do this?

I tried using document.getElementsByTagName("code").getElementsByTagName("a"); and document.getElementsByTagName("code").querySelectorAll("a"); but it doesn t seem to work

`document.getElementsByTagName("code").getElementsByTagName("a");`

VM1278:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at :1:39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.querySelectorAll(selectors)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

```js
const matches = document.querySelectorAll('code a');
console.log(matches);
```

```html
<code>
  <a>Test</a>
  <p>Other tag</p>
  <a>Example</a>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the initial element search, since it returns an HTMLCollection of elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
var all = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var tempElements = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
    all = [...tempElements, ...all];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
document.querySelectorAll('code a').length
```

The `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` functions accept CSS-like DOM selectors and return a node or NodeList, respectively.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.querySelector("code > a");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementById("thediv").getElementsByTagName("a");
alert("The Div has " + anchors.length + " links in it");
```

```html
<div id="thediv">
  <a href="#">link 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 3</a>
</div>
```